# How to permanently swap esc and caps lock in xfce / xubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, xfce, xkb, xmodmap

I followed some post a while ago, and it said to make an `~/.xmodmap` file like so:

```
! Swap caps lock and escape
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

I did, and it now I can swap `esc` and `caps lock` by doing `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap`. I wanted this to be permanent, so I added that command to my `~/.bash_profile`, but it doesn't seem to work; I still have to manually `xmodmap`. As an EEng dropout, I am tempted to just rewire my keyboard }:-) but I know there must be a better way. How can I make this work, permanently?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Execute xfce4-settings-manager, in `Session and Startup` -> `Application autostart`, add an entry, which executes `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap`

Or rename the file to `~/.Xmodmap`

Comment: I renamed the file (it worked!), but I am surprised that my .bash_profile method didn't work. I thought my bash-fu was not weak :P

Comment: I use a Rosewill USB 2.0 switcher (RCUS-17001) to share my keyboard among two PCs, and this option would revert behavior after switching to the other PC output and back. Same for the `setxkbmap` options. [Adding an X config file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334075) worked best for me.

Answer (score 8):

`xkb` has an option that does just that:

```
caps:swapescape      Swap ESC and Caps Lock
```

so you could simply add<sup>1</sup>

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "caps:swapescape"
```

to your XFCE autostart items.

---

<sup>1: there might be a better way to do this but I'm not a XFCE user</sup>

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot on my next reboot. Xmodmap doesn't quite work perfectly for me, I have to manually trigger it after switching keyboard languages, for example. I'm also not on XFCE anymore. That was cool, but I wanted more control at home (Arch) and better interop with the stuff my colleagues use at work (vanilla Ubuntu).

Comment: @DanRoss - Well, if you're using _gnome_ (the only DE that I'm familiar with) it's as simple as adding `caps:swapescape` to your [`xkb-options`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212067)

Answer (score 6):

In Xfce on Opensuse I swapped my <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys by editing the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` file as explained at [the archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Using_X_configuration_files).  I added a line that says

```
Option "XkbOptions" "caps:swapescape"
```

to the section that starts with

```
Section "InputClass"
```

then restarted my computer and the deed was done.

Back up the file before you edit it.  If you make a mistake your gui might not start and you will have to restore or edit the file from a command prompt.  In Ubuntu I recall that I had to put add the option line in a keyboard configuration file that had a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Using the .Xmodmap didn't work for me.

However, a quick man xmodmap says that this works and did:

```
.xmodmaprc
```

which can be executed:

```
xmodmap .xmodmaprc
```

EDIT: ack...I'm wrong...the default did change a few years ago to .Xmodmap
from .xmodmaprc. Creating the .Xmodmap file caused my xfce to load "funny".
In .bash_profile, I put:

```
xmodmap .xmodmaprc
```

Then it worked, and I have a script that restarted my Xfce so it all works.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and change

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"
```

This works for all users, and also when not logged in.

(Xmodmap settings get lost when you plug in/out external keyboards (including usb headphones with volume keys since they register as (very small) keyboards), *unless* the file is named ~/.Xmodmap, but then XFCE will delay applying its own keyboard shortcuts (super-d for show desktop, super-left for tile-left etc.) for 10 seconds after login/unlock. So I wouldn't recommend using Xmodmap on XFCE.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment about losing Xmodmap settings! setxkbmap had the same problem, and your answer clued me into the fact that I'm using a USB switcher, and Caps would revert after switching.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

xfce desktop system keyboard has option to do it on mx linux, not sure about other distros.

Answer (score 0):

I'd been performing a similar adjustment (`/usr/bin/setxkbmap -variant altgr-intl -option 'ctrl:nocaps'`) by putting it in the application autostart, as mentioned by another answer. However, at some point it stopped working for me, so here's my alternative approach:

From the Settings menu, choose "Removable Drives and Media", then the "Input Devices" tab. Enable the option to "Automatically run a program when a USB keyboard is connected" and enter the setkbmap command of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this command into a bash (`something.sh`) file, then add it to startup applications.

```bsh
setxkbmap -option caps:escape
```

And if you wanted to rid of it, just do this:

```bsh
setxkbmap -option
```

Comment: don_crissti has already posted `setxkbmap -option "caps:swapescape"` [as an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66775/80216#245142).  Since the question asks how to ***swap*** Esc and Caps Lock, I wonder why you believe that this is a better answer (or even a correct one at all).  Can you justify your claim that your answer works?  Do you claim that you answer works better than don’s? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.  Include references, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the command `xfconf-query -c keyboard-layout -p /Default/XkbOptions -l -v` in a terminal in order to see your current settings. In my case before remapping CAPS LOCK it was `/Default/XkbOptions/Group  grp:shifts_toggle`. In order to swap esc with caps lock I used `xfconf-query -c keyboard-layout -p /Default/XkbOptions/Group -s "grp:shifts_toggle,caps:swapescape"`. NOTE: There is a caveat, I appended `,caps:swapescape` string to my current value string, because doing just `-s "caps:swapescape"` would overwrite my previously `grp:shifts_toggle` value otherwise. You can also use Settings Editor (frontend GUI for xfconf) for the matter which is provided by XFCE.