# Gnome 3: enable Ctrl+Alt+Bksp on a per-user basis without editing any files?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I would like to enable the `Control + Alt + Backspace` sequence to kill the X server, plus other sequences, without editing any files, if possible (or at least, no system files).

Comment: Check [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375/how-to-enable-killing-xorg-with-ctrlaltbackspace) on re-enabling Ctrl-Alt-Backspace.

Comment: @AbelCheung : Thanks, but that would be a system-wide setting.  I want a customization for one user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Bksp</kbd> on a per-user basis by adding the option

```
terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

to gnome [*xkb-options*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66657) via `gsettings` or `dconf-editor`.
The easiest way is with `dconf-editor` - go to *org > gnome > desktop > input-sources* and add `terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp` to the *xkb-options*, e.g

[image]

With `gsettings` it's a bit more complicated. You'll have to get the existing options (if any) with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

If the output is `@as []` that means there's no option set so you can simply run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']"
```

otherwise you'll have to rewrite the whole array of values + the new value, e.g.:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:nocaps', 'terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']"
```

As I said in my other post, values are delimited by *comma+space*.