# How to toggle "use caps as ctrl" via script?

Tags: gnome

GNOME Tweaks has a toggle to change the caps lock to ctrl:

[image]

How can I do either of the following via a bash script?

- Toggle the setting so that I can see it enabled inside Tweaks
- Just toggle the functionality (caps lock -> ctrl) itself, without changing the Tweaks setting

Answer (score 1):

To enable:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"`

To disable:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"`

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/971067/how-can-i-script-the-settings-made-by-gnome-tweak-tool

EDIT: To address Don's comment below you can run `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` to see if any other `xkb-options` are already set. If there are you can incorporate them too in the gsetting command, for example you might have `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['altwin:menu', 'caps:ctrl_modifier']"`

Comment: Note that while both your commands work fine, they will delete any other `xkb` options already present... see my post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212067)... so scripting this via shell is not that simple. An easier way imo is via `python`'s `Gio.Settings`

Comment: That's a fair point, @don_crissti. I've updated my answer to at least partially address this issue.