# mapping command key to esc in linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, macintosh

I recently installed linux on my Macbook Pro and I'm currently configuring it.

Since I'm a Vim user, I use <kbd>Esc</kbd> key a lot. So I map <kbd>esc</kbd> key to right <kbd>Command</kbd> key and map right <kbd>Command</kbd> key to use it without crossing my hands on my keyboard. In macOS, I used [Karabinder-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) to map those keys.

How can I do the same in linux?

Comment: You sure can, but FWIW I'm a massive vim user and [never use escape](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key)! I use the `jk` trick.

Comment: No worries. For the swapping part specifically, I'd use xkb. There are [a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control) [few](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139128/adding-custom-setxkbmap-options) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66775/how-to-permanently-swap-esc-and-caps-lock-in-xfce-xubuntu) that are similar.

Comment: I used xkb, but when I press command key, the window is disabled and I can't see the keycode of command key.